# About fourier transform in the PDE

Tags: partial-differential-equations, fourier-analysis

In the PDE as below$$ \partial_t u - \frac{i}{\rho} ( - \partial_x^2 )^{\rho /2}  u = 0 \;\;\;(t,x) \in \Bbb R^2 $$ 
How can I prove that $$ (- \partial_x ^2 )^{\rho/ 2} = \scr F ^{-1} | \xi |^\rho \scr F $$ where $\scr F$ is Fourier transform. Is this just definition?

Comment: What is the meaning of $(-\partial_x^2)^{\frac{\rho}{2}}u$ ?

Answer (score 1):

Using properties of the Fourier transform, we can write the Laplacian operator as a [Fourier multiplier](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplier_%28Fourier_analysis%29)
$$(-\Delta)f = [|\xi|^2\hat{f}(\xi)]^{\vee}$$
Generalizing this idea, define the operator $D_x^\alpha$
$$D_x^\alpha f = (-\Delta)^{\alpha/2}f = [|\xi|^\alpha\hat{f}(\xi)]^{\vee}$$
which is referred to as the *homogeneous derivative* or [fractional Laplacian](http://www.ma.utexas.edu/mediawiki/index.php/Fractional_Laplacian). The inverse is the [Riesz potential](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riesz_potential).